# How to set Azure DevOps variable from Visual Studio Test task so the following inline PowerShell script can read it?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to set an Azure DevOps variable in the Release pipeline during a Visual Studio Test task. From within the Visual Studio C# Test code, I want to set an ADO Release variable based on whether a test passes or not. Then I will read in this variable in the following Release task, an inline Powershell script, to execute separate tasks.

I have tried to use the `Console.WriteLine("##vso[task.setvariable variable=<VARIABLE_NAME>;]<VALUE>")` in my C# Visual Studio Test code, but it does not set the variable. However, when I use an inline Powershell script to set the variable using `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=<VARIABLE_NAME>;]<VALUE>"` it works correctly.

Is it possible to set the ADO Release variable using C# from within a Visual Studio Test task? Or can you only set variables using a Batch/Powershell/Shell script/task? If that's the case, does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: vstest redirects the console output to the trx file. This causes the statement to not reach the agent log stream. Thatlast part is required for the agent to update the variable.

Comment: @jessehouwing Is it possible to force the statement to reach the agent log and not get redirected to the TRX file? If not, is there any other way to set the ADO variable from the VS Test task?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/799

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I ended up using a non-Azure ADO approach to solve my problem as the Logging Commands don't work for the VSTest task. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> How to set Azure DevOps variable from Visual Studio Test task so the following inline PowerShell script can read it?

Indeed, just like jessehouwing said:

> ```
> vstest redirects the console output to the trx file.
> ```

So, we need use the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to invoke a logging command.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following method:

Add two inline powershell task to set the an ADO Release variable based on the results of the previous tasks (Including VS Test task):

[image]

Then add another powershell task to set the an ADO Release variable based when the results of all the previous task successfully (Including VS Test task).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's a good idea but I'm not sure it'll work for my case. My `VSTest` task runs multiple tests (call it `TestA`, `TestB`, and `TestC`). My `powershell script` has functions (`FuncA`, `FuncB`, `FuncC`) that are supposed to run if their respective tests in the `VSTest` task passes (if `TestA` and `TestC` pass but `TestB` fails, only `FuncA` and `FuncC` run, but not `FuncB`). In your suggestion, the powershell scripts run based on if ANY of the VSTest tests pass or ANY fail. I need a more itemized approach, hence _ideally_ setting variables from within the tests themselves

Comment: @aboublemc, you said "if TestA and TestC pass but TestB fails, only FuncA and FuncC run, but not FuncB", if you only have this specify situation, or this is just one of your situations, you eventually want to perform the corresponding Func task according to different test results? If you only have this specify situation, we still could use about method, just put task `TestA` and `TestC` together.